# Make \mathcolon to be U+003C in unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

There are several methods to input the colon-like symbols in `unicode-math`:

- Literal `:` (`U+003C`)
- `\mathcolon` (defined as `U+003C`)
- `\mathratio` (defined as `U+2236`)
- `\colon` (`:` with special spaces)

When using the default settings (`colon=TeX`), all the things are mapped to `U+2236`. With `colon=literal`, however, `\mathratio` becomes `U+2236` while the others are `U+003C`.

I hope to make only `\mathcolon` to be the "real" colon, i.e. `U+003C`, how can I do that?

PS: This question is related to [issue #15](https://github.com/Stone-Zeng/FiraMath/issues/15) in Fira Math.